# how to pass a parameter from useEffect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am struggling with passing a parameter from useEffect.
In the POST method shown below, an ID is generated (res.data._id), but I don't know how I can pass it to the next method used later

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .post('/api/hist', {
                user,
                collId: `${id}`,
                answers
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('id:', res.data._id)

            });
    }, []);
```

another method is used each time the button is clicked

```
    const saveAnswer = (answer: string, isCorrect?: boolean) => async () => {
 

        axios
            .post('/api/answer', {
                isCorrect: isCorrect,
                flashcardId: answer
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data)
 
                });
    };
```

but here I would like to use this ID generated earlier as histID
:

```
            .post('/api/answer', {
                isCorrect: isCorrect,
                flashcardId: answer,
                histID: ???

            })
```

does anyone know how to achieve it?

Comment: Where is `id` variable declared and value generated to begin with? Can it not be used again in other functions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do but I'm trying to help you.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'

 const App = () => {
 /**
 * I don't know where is your
 *  - user
 *  - answers
 *  - id
 */
 const [histID,setHistID] = useState(null);

 const getHistID = async () => {
  try {
   const {data} = await axios.post('/api/hist',{
     user,
     collId: `${id}`,
     answers
   })
   if(data){
     setHistID(data.id)
   }
  } catch (error) {
   console.log('getHistID', error);
  }
 };

 useEffect(() => {
  getHistID();
 },[])

 const saveAnswer = async (answer: string, isCorrect?: boolean) => {
  try {
   const {data} = await axios.post('/api/answer',{
     isCorrect: isCorrect,
     flashcardId: answer,
     histID,
   })
   console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
   console.log('saveAnswer', error);
  }
 }

 return (
   // your render
 )
}

export default App
```